# Metro App SuspensionManager Override SaveState Behaviour

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, c#-5.0, winrt-async

How do I modify the `SuspensionManager` object in a Metro App, to `SaveState` for the `MainPage` only and discard **State** and **Navigation** for any child pages?

E.g. I have a `MainPage` that allows you to **Navigate** to a `ChildPage`. If the Metro App is `Closed` or `Suspended`, I want the `ChildPage` to override the `MainPage` state values.

Now, the next time the user opens the app, the `MainPage` should open and not the `ChildPage`. Also the `MainPage` should show State that the `ChildPage` updated before the app was `Closed` or `Suspended`.

Any ideas on how the `SuspensionManager` object can be safely modified to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from **Danielovich** (*which is NOT complete*), the solution is 2 parts:

**Firstly:**

- No longer save state in the `pageState` object, instead save state
  using the `SessionState` object. Why? This is so that all `Pages` can share the same `State` information.

**Secondly:**

- To ensure, that `NavigationState` is not saved so that `MainPage` is always the default page, we need to change the `SaveFrameNavigationState` in `SuspensionManager` as follows:

  ```
  private static void SaveFrameNavigationState(Frame frame)
  {
      var frameState = SessionStateForFrame(frame);
      frame.GetNavigationState();
      frameState["Navigation"] = "1,1,0,15,Skycap.MainPage,12,0";
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add your data from the ChildPage to the SessionState dictionatry and fill it into the MainPage when the app resumes ?

You don't even need to modify the SuspensionManager for doing that!

```
public BasicPage1() {
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Application.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;
    Application.Current.Resuming += Current_Resuming;
}

void Current_Resuming( object sender, object e ) {
    var name = SuspensionManager.SessionState["name"].ToString();
}

void Current_Suspending( object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e ) {
    SuspensionManager.SessionState.Add( "name", "danielovich" );
}
```